# filter issues with getJSON return call in Typeahead (AngularJS directive)

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, typeahead.js

I am having trouble with the filter function in Typeahead. When I am using a static list (see `$scope.statesWithFlags` below), then the filter works as expected, i.e. it only shows those results that match the input query.

```
$scope.statesWithFlags = [{
    'name': 'Alabama',
    'flag': '5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'
  }, {
    'name': 'Alaska',
    'flag': 'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'
  }, {
    'name': 'Arizona',
    'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'
  }, {
    'name': 'Connecticut',
    'flag': '9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'
  }];
```

However, when I use a simple `getJSON` call, which outputs exactly the same `$scope.statesWithFlags` result, then all the possible results keep showing up, and the filter function, `| filter:{name:$viewValue}`, doesn't seem to work. Same thing goes for `limitTo:6`. Do I have to explicitly return the response? If so, how?

```
$scope.statesWithFlags = $.getJSON('/typeahead');
```

This is the input element I am using:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a callback function to get the response and then assigning. Because `$.getJSON('/typeahead')` is a request object not the response from your server.

```
$.getJSON('/typeahead',function(response){
    //parse your response and assign it
    $scope.statesWithFlags = response;
});
```

P.D: Why use `jQuery` ajax calls, when you can `$http` angular module.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. Still getting used to angular, so will check out $http

Comment: @koend yep, try to avoid using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

In case above answer has not helped people using $http call in angularjs and whose api response is too big, in my case it is 70,000 lines:
I recently came across same issue in my angularjs application. I had used this in my HTML:
`<input class="form-control" style="text-overflow: ellipsis" id="diagnosis-list" type="text" ng-model="diagnosis" typeahead="searchDiagnosis as searchDiagnosis.type_code + ' &nbsp : ' + searchDiagnosis.type_code_value for searchDiagnosis in getMatchingDiagnosisList($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="selectDiagnosis($item)`">

The getMatchingDiagnosisList() was written in controller as follows:

```
$scope.getMatchingDiagnosisList = function($viewValue){
      console.log("$viewValue",$viewValue);
      if($viewValue.length == 2 || $viewValue.length > 2){
        console.log("$viewValue.length",$viewValue.length);
            xService.getDiagnosticList($viewValue).then(function(response){
           $scope.searchDiagnosis = {};
          if(response.data.typeCode){
          $scope.searchDiagnosis = response.data;
        }
        else{
           $scope.searchDiagnosis = {'typeCode':[]};
        }

        }).catch(function(){
           $scope.searchDiagnosis = {'typeCode':[]};
        });  
        return $scope.searchDiagnosis.typeCode;
    }
    };
```

which was calling angularjs service which had rest API call in it as follows:

```
getDiagnosticList: function(value){
        var url = URL.matchingDiagnosticList.replace("SEARCH_STRING",value)
         return $http.get(url, {
          headers: headerService.getHeader()
        }).success(function(response) {
          return response;
        });
      }
```

This code did not work because of rest API call so after lot of debugging i edited my controller function as:

```
    $scope.getMatchingDiagnosisList = function($viewValue){
          $scope.isLoading = true;
//Whatever you return below will be taken as a parameter in getMatchesAsync() of the directive, so modify the directive accordingly
            return patientService.getDiagnosticList($viewValue);    
          };          
    };
```

In my case i modified directive getmatchesasync() in the path bower_components\angular-bootstrap\ui-bootstrap-tpls.js or bower_components\angular-bootstrap\ui-bootstrap.js as follows:

```
var getMatchesAsync = function(inputValue) {
      var locals = {$viewValue: inputValue};
      isLoadingSetter(originalScope, true);
      isNoResultsSetter(originalScope, false);
      $q.when(parserResult.source(originalScope, locals)).then(function(matchesFull) {
        //it might happen that several async queries were in progress if a user were typing fast
        //but we are interested only in responses that correspond to the current view value
        var matches = matchesFull.data.typeCode;
        var onCurrentRequest = (inputValue === modelCtrl.$viewValue);
        if (onCurrentRequest && hasFocus) {
          if (matches && matches.length > 0) {

            scope.activeIdx = focusFirst ? 0 : -1;
            isNoResultsSetter(originalScope, false);
            scope.matches.length = 0;

            //transform labels
            for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
              locals[parserResult.itemName] = matches[i];
              scope.matches.push({
                id: getMatchId(i),
                label: parserResult.viewMapper(scope, locals),
                model: matches[i]
              });
            }

            scope.query = inputValue;
            //position pop-up with matches - we need to re-calculate its position each time we are opening a window
            //with matches as a pop-up might be absolute-positioned and position of an input might have changed on a page
            //due to other elements being rendered
            recalculatePosition();

            element.attr('aria-expanded', true);

            //Select the single remaining option if user input matches
            if (selectOnExact && scope.matches.length === 1 && inputIsExactMatch(inputValue, 0)) {
              scope.select(0);
            }
          } else {
            resetMatches();
            isNoResultsSetter(originalScope, true);
          }
        }
        if (onCurrentRequest) {
          isLoadingSetter(originalScope, false);
        }
      }, function() {
        resetMatches();
        isLoadingSetter(originalScope, false);
        isNoResultsSetter(originalScope, true);
      });
    };
```